# Photoshop to Bridge to PDF: Text Quality Degradaton

Tags: adobe, photoshop

I have a text document designed in photoshop, its all text, but when I saves the images and then use Bridge to export them as a PDF, the text quality isn't sharp and contains blurriness around the text.  Haven't been able to find the correct export setting to fix this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop isn't great for creating PDFs with a lot of text, because it's designed to work with raster images instead of vectors. If you've got access to Illustrator, I'd recommend using it instead.

That said, this question seems at least semi-related, and you might find it useful:

[Saving a photoshop document as a .pdf results in blurry / pixelated images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578303/saving-a-photoshop-document-as-a-pdf-results-in-blurry-pixelated-images)